# heatmap with category data

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I'm trying to draw a heatmap via gnuplot. The problem is: how to accumulate data with gnuplot.
Starting with one dataset:

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 2
1 1 3
```

that can be easily plot via

```
set view map
splot 'test.data' using 2:1:3 with image
```

The problem is: there is not only one dataset, but many. See this example data:

```
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 2
1 1 3
0 0 3
0 1 2
1 0 1
1 1 20
```

It has repeating x/y-values. Is it possible to use gnuplot to sum up the third column (the "data-column" like displayed here:

```
0 0 0       0 0 3       0 0 3
0 1 1       0 1 2       0 1 3
1 0 2   +   1 0 1   =   1 0 3
1 1 3       1 1 20      1 1 23
```

My first idea was to use `every` like in `plot 'test.data' using 2:1:3 every 4 with image`. But this doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

For the interested ones: i want to plot a heatmap of my fitbit data:
https://gist.github.com/senfi/c0d13a2c91fae13bc5f5
This file contains nine weeks of counted steps i made. the first column is the day of the week (sunday to saturday). The second column represents 5-minute-steps through the day starting at 0:00am. Plotting a single week looks nice, but plotting the sum/average of the last two years may look pretty awesome. Of course, i will post a picture, if we figure it out how to plot this. Feel free to use the steps-data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for `awk` to me. `awk` can be called from within `gnuplot` like this:

```
sp '<awk ''{a[$1,$2]+=$3}END{for(i in a){split(i,s,SUBSEP);print s[2],s[1],a[i]}}'' test.data' w image
```

The awk script accumulates the value of the third column into the array `a`. The key for each value is the string `[$1 SUBSEP $2]` (equivalent to `[$1,$2]`). `$N` is the value of column `N`. `SUBSEP` is a built in variable whose value we don't need to worry about, we just refer to it again later.

When the whole file has been read (the `END` block), `split` is used to recover the first two columns by breaking up the array keys. The two parts of the key are printed, followed by the accumulated value. I rearranged the column order in awk as well (`print s[2],s[1],a[i]`) so that back in gnuplot, `using 2:1:3` is no longer needed.

Comment: Sometimes, i get scared of the abilities of ````awk````!

Comment: It still needs some fine tuning, but take a look at the steps-data of the last nine weeks: [image](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bm-wsp9CYAEeoV4.png:large)

Comment: @Tobias Nice graph. I have just added to my explanation, so hopefully it is more clear now. `awk` is a really useful tool, worth getting to grips with. Good luck!

Comment: Ah, tanks for the explanation. I had to look at the code a few times, before i figured out what is happening and finally got it. However i missed the rearranging part at the end. Thanks for that!